# If-None-Match, ETag in HTTP with RestSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

Etag is well defined in HTTP specs. More explanation available here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag

Recently I tried to use RestSharp client library with ASP.Net Web API, However I had some issue with caching, I am sending Etag from server side ( i.e.  “ETag” : “12345” as a response header) to client and I can see same Etag in response header in RestResponse object, So far happy.

Now in next request, using same RestSharp client, I expect RestSharp to pass 'If-None-Match' header (i.e.  “If-None-Match” : “12345” as a request header)  in subsequent request to server for same Resource, but unfortunately I cannot find a way to set RestSharp to do it automatically.

Note: WebClient class in c# does that job in raw operation, But RestSharp doesn’t.

What I want is, someone to confirm how to do it, Or just tell me I am rubbish :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what I see in the source, you'll need to add that header yourself on the next request for that resource.

Answer (score 1):

RestSharp uses `HttpWebRequest` behind the scenes. I ran this line of code during initialization of my client, and I started getting the `If-None-Match` header automatically.

```
HttpWebRequest.DefaultCachePolicy = new HttpRequestCachePolicy(HttpRequestCacheLevel.Default);
```

This tells the `HttpWebRequest` to use the default cache level (without this line, it seems that the cache level is set to `HttpRequestCacheLevel.BypassCache`).

Comment: Do you have any idea why this is setting If-Range header instead of If-None-Match for me?

Comment: @bsthomsen Sorry, I haven't dealt with `If-Range` before. Feel free to open a new question if you don't see a similar question already.